# Запись русской кириллицы в csv

Tags: python, csv

При парсинге получаю данные и записываю их в csv 
*[класс save_file]*
Без указания юникода = ошибка
При указании utf8 = Кракозябры вместо русских символов
При указании utf16 = Все как надо, но все столбцы записываются в одну строчку

Как сделать запись как при utf8, но с кириллицей?

**Мой код (весь):**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import os


URL = 'https://www.avito.ru/gelendzhik/kvartiry/sdam/na_dlitelnyy_srok-ASgBAgICAkSSA8gQ8AeQUg' # Cылка что парсим
HEADERS = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.125 Safari/537.36', 'accept': '*/*'}
HOST = 'https://www.avito.ru' # Используем если ссылка на обьявление хитрая и без этого начала
FILE = 'House.csv' # Имя файла

def get_html(url, params = None):
    r = requests.get(url, headers = HEADERS, params = params)
    return r

## Получаем колво страниц ##
def get_pages_count(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    pageinate = soup.find_all('span', class_ = 'pagination-item-1WyVp') # Передаем блок со стрелками и нумерацией страниц
    if pageinate:
        return int(pageinate[-2].get_text()) # Здесь указываем последнюю стр. (должно быть -1, но у нас последний элемент стрелка)
    else:
        return 1

## Записываем контент ##
def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser') # Передаем страницу и указываем что работаем с html
    items = soup.findAll('div', class_ = 'item-with-contact') # Выбираем контейнер в котором лежит искомы обьект. Одна ячейка списка целиком
    hause = [] # Пустой словарь для найденного

    for item in items:
        hause.append({# Добавляем в наш слорь обьекты
            'title' : item.find('a', class_ = 'snippet-link').get_text(strip = True),
            'link' : HOST + item.find('a', class_ = 'snippet-link').get('href'),
            'price' : item.find('span', class_ = 'snippet-price').get_text(strip = True),
            'address' : item.find('span', class_ = 'item-address__string').get_text(strip = True),
        })
    return hause
# 'link' : HOST + item.find('a', class_ = 'ListingItemTitle-module__link').get('href'), / .find_next('span') Аналогичный поиск дальше

## Сохранение ##
def save_file(items, path): # Что сохраняем , куда
    with open(path, 'w', newline='', encoding='utf8') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=';') # Указываем таблицу
        writer.writerow(['Обьявление', 'Ссылка', 'Цена', 'Адрес']) # Указываем титульные столбцы
        for item in items:
            writer.writerow([item['title'], item['link'], item['price'], item['address']])

## Сам парсер ##
def parse():
#    URL = input('Введите URL: ')
#    URL = URL.strip()
    html = get_html(URL)
    if html.status_code == 200: # Статус 200 - сайт отвечает
        house = []
        pages_count = get_pages_count(html.text)
        for page in range(1, pages_count + 1):
            print(f'Парсинг страницы {page} из {pages_count}')
            html = get_html(URL, params={'p' : page}) # Передаем страницу (в ключе указываем то как указывается страница на сайте)
            house.extend(get_content(html.text)) # Заносим данные в список
        save_file(house, FILE)
        print (f'Получено {len(house)} обьявлений')
        os.startfile(FILE)
    else:
        print('Ошибка URL \ Сайт не отвечает')


parse()
```

Comment: У меня в Colab выдаёт 403 - forbidden по этой ссылке

Comment: А вообще какая у вас ОС и чем вы смотрите файл? Виндовые тулзы могут ожидать файл в cp1251 и не понимать utf-8. Я смотрю файлы обычно в FAR Manager, там можно выбрать любую кодировку

Comment: Если не указывать, автоматически выбирается ср1251, но она при записи выдает ошибку. Открытие файла только через Exel

Comment: Хорошо, попробуйте encoding = “utf-16”, где-то тут читал, что Excel такое нормально читает

Comment: наличие кракозябр скорее всего определяется просмотрщиком

Comment: Если использовать кодировку utf-16 и в csv.writer прописывать delimiter='\t' - в Exel на виндовс всё нормально открывается.